# Cloudformation Stack Versioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, version-control, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to provide version control for Cloudformation Stacks?

I am running an enviroment build completly using nested CF stacks. I know I could use Github for this, but as I am running nested stacks, I need to keep it on S3 (TemplateURL requires S3 as source for your files). Moreover, the enviroment has to be private, so no public accesssible resources are allowed.

Thanks !!!
Michal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this; I recommend using CodeCommit and perhaps following the Validation Pipeline model outlined here: https://aws.amazon.com/answers/devops/aws-cloudformation-validation-pipeline/
Beyond versioning your templates, you can also leverage the process for validating templates, do pre- and post- tests, etc.

- Luis

Comment: I guess the answer is not valid anymore since the Validation Pipeline solution is no longer available according to AWS.